# Django Isolated Subdomains

Tags: python, django, web-applications, subdomain

Let's say we have a model called `Event` with a slug `name`. I'm looking to configure my Django app to basically isolate all my other models into separate apps depending on the event. For example:

```
"http://annualmeetup.domain.com" # in the form of "http://{}.domain.com".format(e.name)
```

How would I create completed isolated apps such that my models for users, meetings, and others only work in the context of the given subdomain? I was thinking about writing multiple apps for each event and copying the same models via a command script, but I still don't know how to point an app to a subdomain.

Comment: Have you considered using the built-in ["sites" framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/sites/)

Comment: @HåkenLid I haven't seen that before. Could you demonstrate an example?

Comment: I don't really have much experience with it.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi, there's [a short example on the Sites framework documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/sites/#associating-content-with-multiple-sites)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to use [django-tenant-schemas](https://github.com/bernardopires/django-tenant-schemas) which is designed for this purpose:

> Django provides currently no simple way to support multiple tenants using the same project instance, even when only the data is different. Because we don't want you running many copies of your project, you'll be able to have:
>
> - Multiple customers running on the same instance
> - Shared and Tenant-Specific data
> - Tenant View-Routing *(i.e., subdomain mapping)*

This will result in you having separate database schema for each tenant (event, in your case), each with its own isolated models. Without too much effort you can create tenants (events) on the fly - it sounds like your use case would require that.

Note: `tenant-schemas` only work with Postgres.

Comment: Is there an alternative for sqlite?

Comment: Why would you want to use sqlite? It's not really a backend for production environments. https://sqlite.org/whentouse.html

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to write separate apps for each event. If each event shares the same schema, you could just make your architecture [Multitenant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitenancy)

Here are all the packages available for this. [Link here](https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/multi-tenancy/)

I personally recommend `django-hosts` But it doesn't offer good data-isolation features. This is good if you already have an existing project and just want to introduce multitenancy. However, if you are just starting the project, `django-tenancy` is a great option.